# Kotlin functional strategy pattern doesn't compile

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I'm trying to put several functions in a map. The idea is to have: `Map<String, [function]>`.

The code is as follows:

```
class UserIdQueriesHandler {

    val strategy: Map<String, KFunction2<@ParameterName(name = "id") String, @ParameterName(name = "options") Array<Options>, Answer>> =
        mapOf( // the compiler complains here
            "d" to ::debt,
            "p" to ::currentProduct
        )

    fun debt(id: String, options: Array<DebtOptions>): UserDebt = UserDebt(isPresent = true, amount = 0.0)

    fun currentProduct(id: String, options: Array<CurrentProductOptions>): UserProducts = UserProducts(products = emptyList())
}

enum class DebtOptions : Options { BOOL, AMOUNT }

enum class CurrentProductOptions : Options { ALL, PRINT, DIGITAL, ENG, HEB, TM }

data class UserDebt(val isPresent: Boolean, val amount: Double) : Answer
data class UserProducts(val products: List<Int>): Answer
```

`Answer` and `Options` are simple kotlin interfaces:

```
interface Answer
interface Options
```

Compiler output:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
Map<String, KFunction2<@ParameterName String, @ParameterName Array<Options>, Answer>>
found:
Map<String, KFunction2<@ParameterName String, {[@kotlin.ParameterName] Array  & [@kotlin.ParameterName] Array }, Answer>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `strategy` says functions you put into it can accept any `Array<Options>` as the second argument, which `debt` and `currentProduct` can't.

The simplest workaround would be to change their argument type to `Array<Options>` (or `List<Options>`; they probably don't need to mutate it!) and fail at runtime if wrong options are passed or ignore them.

[Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) section in the documentation is also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since an `Array` can be both read and written, its type parameter is [invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance). This makes it so that you can't assign an `Array<DebtOptions>` to a variable that has the type of `Array<Options>`. The former isn't a subtype of the latter, because it would allow you to put other elements in the array that are `Options`, but not `DebtOptions`, leading to problems to code that has a reference to this array as an `Array<DebtOptions>`.

A solution would be to make your functions accept `Array<Options>`, if you can.

```
val strategy: Map<String, KFunction2<String, Array<Options>, Answer>> =
        mapOf(
                "d" to ::debt,
                "p" to ::currentProduct
        )

fun debt(id: String, options: Array<Options>): UserDebt = ...

fun currentProduct(id: String, options: Array<Options>): UserProducts = ...
```

You could combine this with using the nicer functional type instead of a `KFunction2`:

```
val strategy: Map<String, (String, Array<Options>) -> Answer> = ...
```

Comment: `Array` not being covariant is a bit of a red herring (which is why I didn't mention it in my answer): because functions are contravariant in their arguments, only a contravariant type would type-check, but it makes no sense semantically.

Comment: I'm sort of following, but what doesn't make sense semantically?

Comment: I mean that: 1. If you replace all uses of `Array` by a contravariant type (e.g. `(A) -> Unit`, so `(Options) -> Unit` in `strategy` and `(DebtOptions) -> Unit` in `debt`), the code will compile (maybe with more explicit type annotations). 2. Then you have `fun debt(id: String, options: (DebtOptions) -> Unit): UserDebt = ...`. 3. But then how would you use this second parameter?